# truncating an existing JSON string at a given level of depth - Performance optimization

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, compiler-optimization

i am currently searching for a way to truncate a JSON string in order to improve logging performance and file size.
My plan is truncating the JSON string at a certain level of depth by appending "..." instead of actual data to a StringBuilder, so for example

```
{
  "data":{
    "1":"test",
    "2":"test"
  }
}
```

will become:

```
{
  "data":{...}
}
```

The JSON payload i am trying to log has a length of around 20000 characters. The function i have already written truncates it to around 1000, which is fine for me.
Here's the code:

```cs
int c = 0;
int max = 3; //in the actual code, this is configurable of course.
bool locked = false;
char current;
bool inc = true;
bool insideString = false;
bool escaped = false;
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
//foreach(char current in text) does not seem to improve performance in any meaningful way
{
  inc = false;
  current = text[i];
  if (current == '{') inc = true;
  else if (current == '}') c--;
  if (c < max)
  {
    //handle braces inside strings as suggested by Jeremy Lakeman
    if (!escaped && current == '\"') insideString = !insideString; 
    else if (current == '\\') escaped = true;
    builder.Append(current);
    locked = false;
  }
  else
  {
    if (!locked)
    {
      builder.Append("...");
      locked = true;
    }
  }
  if (inc) c++;
}
```

I have kept the variables outside of the loop in order to avoid any performance overhead that could be created through variable initialization.

Do you think there any way this code's performance could be improved any further?
I'm looking forward to hearing your opinions!

Edit: I've created two methods for benchmarking, one using substrings, one using pure character parsing. Here are the results:

```
[Benchmark]
public void Variant1()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var c = 0;
    char current;
    int max = 3;
    bool insideString = false;
    int next;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
    {
        current = text[i];

        if (current == '\"' && text[i - 1] != '\\')
        {
            insideString = !insideString;
        }

        if (!insideString && (current == '{' || current == '}'))
        {
            int mod = 124 - current;
            c += mod;
            if (c == max - 1 && mod == -1)
            {
                builder.Append("{...");
                continue;
            }
        }

        if (c >= max)
        {
            next = text.IndexOfAny(chars, i + 1);
            if (next >= 0) i = next - 1;
            continue;
        }
        builder.Append(current);
    }
}

[Benchmark]
public void Variant2()
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    var c = 0;
    char current;
    int max = 3;
    bool insideString = false;
    int next = -1;
    int prev = 0;
    while ((next = text.IndexOfAny(chars, next + 1)) >= 0)
    {
        current = text[next];
        if (current == '\"' && text[next - 1] != '\\')
        {
            insideString = !insideString;
        }

        if (c < max) builder.Append(text[prev..next]);
        if (!insideString && (current == '{' || current == '}'))
        {
            int mod = 124 - current;
            c += mod;
            if (c == max && mod == 1)
            {
                builder.Append("{...");
                continue;
            }
        }
        prev = next;
    }
}
```

```
|   Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
|--------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
| Variant1 | 30.94 us | 0.443 us | 0.392 us |
| Variant2 | 30.16 us | 0.582 us | 0.454 us |
```

as you can see, both methods are nearly identical in speed.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader?view=net-6.0 has a `.CurrentDepth` and a `.Skip()` method. But I don't know how easily you can copy to another buffer. Note that your code won't handle `{` in a string.

Comment: *I have kept the variables outside of the loop in order to avoid any performance overhead that could be created through variable initialization.* - For primitive types at least, even JIT compilers aren't braindead and have no problem with having the declarations inside loops at a point where you're ready to initialize it. Your way doesn't actively hurt performance either, compilers are also able to do lifetime analysis of values, and see that even though the variable was declared in an outer scope, any value for `inc` is only used by that iteration, not a later iteration or code after the loop

Comment: Do you still have the data structure the JSON string was built from at this point?  As @Jeremy suggests, it might be faster to re-serialize it in a depth-limited way.  Or might not, depending on how much work that is; converting large integers to decimal digit-strings is somewhat more expensive that just scanning text, and looping over a more complex data structures takes work.

Comment: Are you interested in using CPU-specific SIMD instructions, like x86 / x86-64 SSE4.1 `pcmpistri` to efficiently scan for the next `{` or `}`?  Actually, probably just SSE2 `pcmpeqb` twice is a better bet there, especially since you want to act differently depending on which.  Given a `{` whose inside you want to replace with `...`, you can count `{` and `}`, checking the count only when you see a `}` to see whether that's the end of an inner scope or the one you want.  [How can I count the occurrence of a byte in array using SIMD?](//stackoverflow.com/q/49552656) has AVX2 intrinsics for C#.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman at the point in the system at which this message is being logged, the object itself is no longer available. This means i would have to decode the JSON object and then re-serialize it. I think, this will defeat the perfomance of the current code.
Very good point about the code not being able to handle `{` characters in a string! I will add some logic to skip parsing actual strings.
@PeterCordes thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If you don't need to go back to the drawing board because of the possibility of `"{"` in the JSON, I'd be inclined to write an inner loop that runs when `c >= max`, that runs until you've found the closing `}` for the scope you wanted to skip.  Even if you don't use SIMD to check multiple chars at once, that can be a tighter loop that going through the main loop with both its `if` conditions for input characters you know you're skipping.  (I'm assuming the JIT compiler isn't smart enough to make asm that already does that.)

Comment: I don't think there's any way it compile branchlessly (always copy+store, only conditionally increment the output pointer) since there's too much conditional behaviour.  So there's likely going to be a branch mispredict on transitions between copying outer nesting vs. skipping inner nesting, and this idea shouldn't make that any worse.  But it would make the inner skip loop tighter. IDK if it's worth doing something similar for outer levels to stay in a tighter copy loop until `c` hits the critical value. Basically loop unswitching to get the `if(c < max)` and `if(!locked)` out of inner loops.

Comment: @PeterCordes i've implemented two more simple variables, one for tracking whether i've seen a `"` previously (indicating i'm in a string) and another for tracking if the previous char was \, marking the current character as an escaped one. This seems to be slowing down the loop quite a bit:
`
if (c < max)
{
  if (!escaped && current == '\"') insideString = !insideString; 
  else if (current == '\\') escaped = true;
  builder.Append(current);
  locked = false;
}
`
I like your idea of using another loop for finding the corresponding `}`, i will try that.

Comment: code formatting made a mess of your comment; probably best to [edit] your question with the updated version anyway, especially to describe the bugfix.  (In comments, there are no code *blocks*, just `code` with a single backtick without space between it and the code.)

Comment: Hmm, perhaps we can leverage fast library routines (like an equivalent of C's `memchr`) to separately find the positions of the next `{`, the next `"`, and the next `}`.  I assume C# has some kind of string-search functions that can use internals that can use SIMD internally to go faster than searching 1 char at a time.  But if there are lots of special characters, like more than one per 8 or 16 chars on average, that probably loses.

Comment: @PeterCordes i've just noticed that creating a tight inner loop would mean i'd have to re-check the escaping. Will performance still be better in that case?

Comment: Maybe, if you do it right.  It might help to only check for the previous character being `\ ` *after* finding something else.  You're already using `text[i]`, not an iterator, so it's no problem to look at `text[i-1]` as long as this can't happen on the first char of the string.  But that can't be a `"` that *ends* a double-quoted string so you're fine.

Comment: Your current version still looks buggy, though.  It will count `}` and `{` inside quoted strings in deeply nested scopes it's skipping.  If you build it more like a state machine where you have a loop that goes until you exit this state, that could help.  e.g. inside a quoted string: string-search for a `"`, and then check it's not preceded by a `\ `.  Once you get out, then go back to either skipping or copying, depending on `c`.

Comment: It is possible to parse json using simd instructions https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson, if you really want to invest the time, you could use the same approach to locate the `{}` pairs, work out the depth of each pair, then memcopy only the ranges you want to preserve. But I doubt that level of effort is worth it. However, I would suggest appending a range of characters in one hit instead of one at a time.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman but wouldn't calling IndexOf() in combination with Substring() still mean we'd be iterating over just as many characters?

Comment: @ndrscodes: Yes, but you'd be iterating 16 or 32 bytes at a time, for a similar cost in CPU work to maybe 2 or 3 characters, on a modern x86 CPU.  Assuming a well-optimized IndexOf and block-copy Substring functions.  It's certainly worth trying, especially if your actual data tends to have longer runs without quotes or {} characters, not tons of tiny scopes.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for clarifying. I will definitely try that!

Comment: Sure, read the characters one at a time. But write in chunks. The characters you read will probably still be in cache, but the write should be more efficient. Well, depending on memory alignment at least.